# Constant Time Swap Logic for Vectors in C++ STL

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Why is the time complexity required for swapping contents of two C++ STL vectors independent of the size of the corresponding vectors?

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/

Comment: Because they swap the pointers to the underlying data... (and count/capacity variables)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A typical vector implementation stores:

- The allocator
- A pointer to the first element
- A pointer to the past-the-end position, or equivalently, the size
- A pointer to the end of the memory block owned by the vector, or equivalently, the capacity

`swap()` simply swaps the pointers, and, if `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is true, the allocator. It doesn't do element-wise swap. In fact, no standard container other than `std::array` is allowed to do element-wise swap.